# How @Value in Spring works internally so it could read Kubernetes ConfigMap?

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes

I'm curious on how the `@Value` works internally on Spring so that it can actually read value from `ConfigMap` of Kubernetes Cluster.

I know that:

- `@Value("${my.nested.variable}")` were used to access variables
  declared on `application.properties` or in OS' environment variable
  (higher priority).
- When creating new ConfigMap on kubernetes (for Spring project), you usually do `kubectl create configmap my-config-name --from-file=application.properties`, and it will magically connect those `ConfigMap` values with respective `@Value()` on Spring, of course we have to select `my-config-name` on deployment YAML file.

Notice above that we **didnt expose/map** those configmap to container's environment variable, already checked the inside container with `printenv` , **can't find it**.
However, Spring were still able to retrieve those value from ConfigMap to be used in java program.

How is it possible? anyone know how Spring's `@Value` works or how the `ConfigMap` actually works internally so those two can **magically** connected?

Thank You.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean but there is no magic. You are creating your `ConfigMap` from the same `application.properties` used by `@Values`. This is where the map come from

Comment: [Spring Cloud Kubernetes](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-kubernetes) knows how to [read a ConfigMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#kubernetes-propertysource-implementations), presumably using the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/); I wouldn't expect the magic to be especially magic.

Comment: Hello @xcode. Does the comments above answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer. Feel free to expand it.

As already mentioned by David Maze in the comments, [Spring Cloud Kubernetes](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-kubernetes) is reading [ConfigMaps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#kubernetes-propertysource-implementations) by using [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/). The mechanisms behind it are described in the linked docs.